# why script processor works in reindex api and not working on pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-opendistro

i create idices based on projectId like so:

//By calling reindex API directly,it works fine

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "xxxxx-rlk-test1-2021-07-22"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "xxxxxx",
    "op_type": "create"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
          if (ctx._source.kubernetes != null){
            if (ctx._source.kubernetes.namespace_labels['field_cattle_io/projectId'] != null){
              ctx._index = 'xxxxxx-rlk-'+ (ctx._source.kubernetes.namespace_labels['field_cattle_io/projectId']) + '' + (ctx._index.substring('xxxxxx-rlk-test-'.length(), ctx._index.length()))
            }else {
              ctx._index = 'xxxxxx-rlk-'+ (ctx._source.kubernetes.namespace_labels['field_cattle_io/projectId']) +'-noproject'
            }
          }
      """
  }
}
```

But when i would like to use reindex with pipeline like so:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/group-by-projectid-pipeline
{
  "description": "this pipeline split indices by pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          if (ctx.kubernetes != null){
            if (ctx.kubernetes.namespace_labels['field_cattle_io/projectId'] != null){
              ctx._index = 'xxxxxx-rlk-'+ (ctx.kubernetes.namespace_labels['field_cattle_io/projectId']) +'' + (ctx._index.substring('xxxxxx-rlk-test-'.length(), ctx._index.length()))
            }else {
              ctx._index = 'xxxxxx-rlk-'+ (ctx.kubernetes.namespace_labels['field_cattle_io/projectId']) +'-noproject'
            }
          }
      """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and :

```
POST _reindex
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "xxxxxx-rlk-test1-2021-07-22"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "xxxxxx",
    "pipeline": "group-by-projectid-pipeline",
    "op_type": "create"
  }
}
```

then elasticsearch says (about *(ctx._index.substring('xxxxxx-rlk-test-'.length(), ctx._index.length()))*):

"type" : "string_index_out_of_bounds_exception",
"reason" : "begin 16, end 6, length 6"

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the script do not execute at the same time in both situations.

During the reindex call **without pipeline**, the script is executing before the document lands in the destination index, hence `ctx._index` is the name of the source index, i.e. `xxxxxx-rlk-test1-2021-07-22`, so your substring call works.

During a reindex call **with pipeline**, the script processor runs at the time the document is about to land in the destination index, hence `ctx._index` is the name of the destination index, i.e. `xxxxxx`.

This is the reason by `'...'.substring(16, 6)` doesn't work. So you should proceed differently in the second case.

The easy way out of this (if you want to keep the same logic) is to use a dummy destination index that has the same length as the source one that you're supposed to modify anyway:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "xxxxxx-rlk-test1-2021-07-22"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "xxxxxx-rlk-xxxxx-2021-07-22",        <--- change this
    "pipeline": "group-by-projectid-pipeline",
    "op_type": "create"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Val, with pipeline approach, i would like to know there is a way to get the name of source index ? where source index name has the following pattern: project-*

Comment: Example: project-mdb-30-07-2021, project-mdb-29-07-2021, project-xyrz-29-07-2021

Comment: Let's see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593549/elasticsearch-how-can-i-get-the-name-of-source-index-in-ingest-pipeline-script